# For which $p\geq 1$ is $0=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \bigg( \int |n\cdot 1_{[n,n+1/n^2]}|^p \bigg)^{1/p}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to determine for which $p\geq 1$ and $f_n=n \cdot 1_{[n,n+1/n^2]}$ we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ||f_n||_p=0$$

I have gotten to:
$$||f_n||^2=\bigg( \int |n\cdot 1_{[n,n+1/n^2]}|^p \bigg)^{1/p}$$
$$=\bigg( \int n^p \cdot 1_{[n,n+1/n^2]} \bigg)^{1/p}$$
$$=\bigg( n^p \cdot 1/n^2 \bigg)^{1/p}$$
$$=\bigg(  n^p/n^2 \bigg)^{1/p}$$
$$=  n/n^{2/p} $$
$$= 1/n^{2/p-1} $$

So only for p=1 it seems that this is true.

However this seems as a strange result as the integral should converge

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: your result is right, what help do you need here?

Comment: Well, you need $2/p - 1 >0$, which holds iff $p <2$.